# How to separate a line of grabbed data from webpage for more readability

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Currently, the snippet is running but presents the data being extracted not very presentable. I want to strip the line of data into two.

```
import requests, re, random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}

url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4"
req = requests.get(url,header, timeout=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
creator = soup.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trContract').get_text()
tokentracker = soup.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokeninfo').get_text()

print (creator)
print (tokentracker)
```

Current Output:

```
ContractCreator:
0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436 at txn 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715


TokenTracker:

 StackDoge (STACKDOGE)
```

Wanted Output:

```
Contract Owner: 0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
Transaction ID: 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715

Token Name: StackDoge (STACKDOGE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution you can try out,

```
print("Contract Owner:", creator.find('a', attrs={"title": "Creator Address"}).text)
print("Transaction ID:", creator.find('a', attrs={"title": "Creator Txn Hash"}).text)

print("Token Name:", tokentracker.find("a").text)
```

---

```
Contract Owner: 0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
Transaction ID: 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715
Token Name: StackDoge (STACKDOGE)
```

Comment: It works after I remove the .get_text() part.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
newlist = [x.strip() for x in creator.split("at txn")]
print("Contract Owner: " + newlist[0])
print("Transaction ID: " + newlist[1])
```

Comment: How about the last part of the script: Token Name: StackDoge (STACKDOGE)

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string with " at txn " as separator:

```
txt = "0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436 at txn 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715"

x = txt.split(" at txn ")

print(f'Contract Owner: {x[0]}')
print(f'Transaction ID: {x[1]}')
```

This will print:

```
Contract Owner: 0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
Transaction ID: 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715
```

Comment: How about the last part: Token Name: StackDoge (STACKDOGE)